# Collecting extra user data in Django Social Auth pipeline

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I'm using Django Social Auth (v0.7.22) for registering users via Facebook, and that is working OK.

My doubt is how to collect extra data for new users:

1. How to detect a new user?
2. Where to store the collected data (in the Django session or pass it through pipeline `**kwargs`)?

My pipeline looks like:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.social_auth_user',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.misc.save_status_to_session',
    ## My customs ...
    'myapp.pipeline.load_data_new_user',
    'myapp.pipeline.handle_new_user',
    'myapp.pipeline.username',
    ##
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.associate_user',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.load_extra_data',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.update_user_details',
)
```

The first custom function just collect the Facebook profile picture:

```
def load_data_new_user(backend, response, user, *args, **kwargs):
    if user is None:
        if backend.name == "facebook":
            try:
                url = "http://graph.facebook.com/%s/picture?width=200&height=200&redirect=false" % response['id']
                data = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())['data']
                return {'avatar': data}
            except StandardError:
                return {'avatar': None}
        else:
            raise ValueError()
```

My doubts:

1. I'm checking if `user` is `None` for detecting new users (not sure if it's OK to assume that).
2. I'm storing the avatar metadata in the pipeline's `**kwargs` instead of use sessions, is it OK? When should I use session.

The other custom functions are based on the [Matias Aguirre example](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/tree/master/example), and use sessions 
for storing the username of new users.

```
def handle_new_user(request, user, *args, **kwargs):
    if user is None and not request.session.get('saved_username'):
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/form/')


def username(request, user, *args, **kwargs):
    if user is not None:
        username = user.username
    else:
        username = request.session.get('saved_username')
    return {'username': username}
```

So, I'm not sure when to use sessions or the "correct idiom" for resolve my problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Matias Aguirre (django socialauth creator) gently answered my question in the [DSA google mail list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=es&fromgroups=#!topic/django-social-auth/xzDLi48weRM)

His answer:

> Collecting the data is easy as you saw, but where to put it depends on
>   your  project, what you plan to do with the data, and where you expect
>   it to be  available. For example, if you plan to put the avatar image
>   on a user profile  model, then you should get the profile for the
>   current user and store it there,  if you use a custom user with an
>   avatar_url field, then you should fill that  field after the user was
>   created, if you plan to download the image and store  it local to the
>   server using the username (id, etc) as the filename, then just  do it
>   that way too.
>
> The session is usually used as a mechanism of communication with a
>   view.
>
> Regarding the "user is new", there's a flag "is_new" set to True/False
>   when the  user is new or not, but it's not updated until the
>   "create_user" is called.
>
> The pipeline entry "save_status_to_session" should be placed before
>   the method  that breaks the pipeline flow, in your case
>   handle_new_user.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem trying to get extra data with Tumblr and Instagram until I found [this article](http://tryolabs.com/Blog/2012/02/13/get-user-data-using-django-social-auth/).

There seems to be two ways to popular `extra_data` when a user is created / associated:

## *_EXTRA_DATA

This is the easiest way for many pieces of data, but may not be accessible depending on the circumstances. There is a brief mention of it on the [OAuth page in the docs](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/v0.7.22/backends/oauth.html).

For example, in your settings file:

```
FACEBOOK_EXTRA_DATA = [('<actual field from FB>', '<your alias>')]
```

However, it doesn't appear that the various backends return consistent values, so I had to debug `social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.load_extra_data` in order to find what fields were accessible. Sometimes, the individual backend describes which fields are available (e.g. [see Facebook Backend](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/v0.7.22/backends/facebook.html)), or the API documentation, but the most reliable way is to step through their code.

## Adding to the pipeline

As you've started, you can define a custom function and hook it into the pipeline. From the linked article (and slightly modified):

```
def get_user_avatar(backend, details, response, social_user, uid,\
                user, *args, **kwargs):
    url = None
    if getattr(backend, 'name', None) == 'facebook':
        url = "http://graph.facebook.com/%s/picture?type=large" % response['id']

    if url:
        # Save the image somewhere, or just use the URL
        avatar = url
        social_user.extra_data['avatar'] = avatar
        social_user.save()
```

In either case, once you've done that, the extra data is available via `social_user.extra_data['your_field']`. Hope that helps.

## What about detecting if a user is new or not?

From my understanding, unless you are using `django-socialauth` for account login, the pipeline is only run on the initial association, so the user will always be new at that point. Beyond that, I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: You can detect if the user is new by checking the `is_new` flag passed to pipeline entries.